# Insert elements into std::map without extra copying

Tags: c++, optimization, stdmap, std

Consider this program:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#define log magic_log_function // Please don't mind this.

//
// ADVENTURES OF PROGO THE C++ PROGRAM
//

class element;
typedef std::map<int, element> map_t;

class element {
public:
    element(const std::string&);
    element(const element&);
    ~element();
    std::string name;
};
element::element(const std::string& arg)
    : name(arg)
{
    log("element ", arg, " constucted, ", this);
}
element::element(const element& other)
    : name(other.name)
{
    name += "-copy";
    log("element ", name, " copied, ", this);
}
element::~element()
{
    log("element ", name, " destructed, ", this);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    map_t map1; element b1("b1");
    log(" > Done construction.");
    log(" > Making map 1.");
    map1.insert(std::pair<int, element>(1, b1));
    log(" > Done making map 1.");
    log(" > Before returning from main()");
}
```

It creates some objects on stack and `insert`s them into an `std::map` container, creating **two** extra temporary copies in the process:

```
element b1 constucted, 0x7fff228c6c60
 > Done construction.
 > Making map 1.
element b1-copy copied, 0x7fff228c6ca8
element b1-copy-copy copied, 0x7fff228c6c98
element b1-copy-copy-copy copied, 0x232d0c8
element b1-copy-copy destructed, 0x7fff228c6c98
element b1-copy destructed, 0x7fff228c6ca8
 > Done making map 1.
 > Before returning from main()
element b1 destructed, 0x7fff228c6c60
element b1-copy-copy-copy destructed, 0x232d0c8
```

We can get rid of one extra copy constructor call by changing the `std::pair` signature to `std::pair<int, element&>`, however, the second temporary is still created and immediately destroyed:

```
element b1 constucted, 0x7fff0fe75390
 > Done construction.
 > Making map 1.
element b1-copy copied, 0x7fff0fe753c8
element b1-copy-copy copied, 0x1bc4098
element b1-copy destructed, 0x7fff0fe753c8
 > Done making map 1.
 > Before returning from main()
element b1 destructed, 0x7fff0fe75390
element b1-copy-copy destructed, 0x1bc4098
```

Is there a way to make `std::map` just take an object on stack by reference and make a single internal copy of it?

Comment: The most efficient way would be `map1.emplace(1, "b1");`. But that's not supported everywhere yet. Next best is `map1[1] = "b1";`, though that has slightly different semantics.

Comment: Also note that `map_t::value_type` is **not** `std::pair<int, element>`!

Comment: `#include "log.cpp"` is *really* scary.

Comment: @H2CO3 http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1995029 here are its contents

Comment: @MischaArefiev The fact you're including an implementation (`.cpp`) file itself is scary, not the fact you're not showing its contents.

Comment: Erm, that looks more like a header file with inline template definitions and the wrong extension.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, that's why I asked the readers to not mind it.  The semantics of the program are the same without it and without calls to the log procedure.  I will edit the post so that this include will stop diverting attention from the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard practice (with older C++ versions) where I've been is to use a Map of shared pointers.

Still creates a copy of the shared pointers, but that's usually much less onerous than copying large objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, changing the code to use shared_ptrs was an improvement, performance-wise.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the many use cases which motivated `C++11`'s `move` functionality, supported by a host of new features, particularly rvalue references, and a variety of new standard library interfaces, including `std::map::emplace`, `std::vector::emplace_back`, etc.

If, for whatever reason, you cannot yet use `C++11`, you can at least console yourself with the thought that the problem has been recognized, and that a solution has been standardized and implemented, and that furthermore many of us are using it, some of us [1] in production-code. So, as the old joke has it, *[a solution exists](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1878735)* and it's your call as to when you take it up.

Note that you don't have to use the `emplace` member function if your objects implement move constructors, which they may even do by default. This won't happen if the have explicit copy constructors, so your test above may produce observer effects (and indeed, it might also suppress compiler optimizations in the case of PODs, so even with C++03 you might not have the problem you think you do).

There are a variety of hacks available which kinda-sorta avoid copies with only "minor" source code alterations, but IMHO the best approach is to start moving towards C++11. Whatever you do, try to do it in a way that will make the inevitable migration less painful.

---

[Note 1]: Disclaimer: I no longer write production code, having more or less retired, so I'm not part of the "some of us" in that sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Unfortunately we don't use C++11 yet, so I had to settle for boost's shared_ptrs for now.

Comment: @MischaArefiev, fair enough. I was in that position in my last job, too, and now that I'm free to use C++11, I realize how much pain I went through because I couldn't before. But migration is a massive task, so I'm not criticizing the decision to not use it "yet". Added a sentence to my answer, anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [emplace()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) :

> The element is constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed. The constructor of the element type (value_type, that is, std::pair) is called with exactly the same arguments as supplied to the function

Comment: g++ from gcc 4.7.2 doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you dont have `emplace`, you can construct the element on the heap and pass pointers to map:

```
typedef std::map<int, element*> map_t;
...
printf(" > Making pair 1.\n");
std::pair<int, element*> pair(1, new element ("b1")) ;
printf(" > Making map 1.\n");
map1.insert(pair);
```

but then you are subject to memory-leaks if you dont take care when your map leaves scope...

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I want std::map to manage the element objects, which is not the case when pointers are stored.